# collectionViewLayout Initialization

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uicollectionview

I have initialized my UICollectionView in the storyboard and decided to set a few attributes programmatically; however, those new attributes assignment only take effect when I call `self.collectionView.reloadData()`.

```
let layout = self.collectionView!.collectionViewLayout as! UICollectionViewFlowLayout
layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 0;
```

The storyboard currently has both set to zero yet it loads a `minimumInteritemSpacing` that's not zero when I have them assigned programmatically. I've tried to place the aforementioned three lines of code in my `viewDidLoad()` function and, yet, they did not take effect on initial load.

**I've also tried this:**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAtIndex section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 0
}
```

Still no luck and I'm not sure what else I could try to force both to `0` on the initial load before I call `self.collectionView.reloadData()`.

**Storyboard screenshot of settings:**
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screen shot of your storyboard and simulator?

Comment: Added a screenshot of the storyboard. Nothing really to show in the simulator since it is trivial to look at as I described what occurs on initialization: spacing between items appear at first and then go away after I trigger `self.collectionView.reloadData()` since the three lines of code to set the spacing to 0 is executed as intended.

Comment: Where are you triggering `self.collectionView.reloadData()`?

Comment: I trigger it when the end-user clicks a Result button to calculate and draw the cells within the UICollectionView. I've also tried calling it in `refreshUI()` and `viewDidLoad()` so that it takes effect right away but it still ignores my three lines of code. :-(

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a hack to me, and I can't test it right now so it might not work, but try this:

In `viewDidLoad`:

```
let button = UIButton(type: UIButtonType.System) as! UIButton
button.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100, -100, -100)
button.setTitle("Test Button", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
button.addTarget(self, action: "buttonAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

buttonObj.sendActionsForControlEvents(.TouchUpInside)
```

Then this function:

```
func buttonAction(sender:UIButton!)
{
    self.collectionView.reloadData()
}
```

This will create a button outside the frame (so the user never sees it). Then it gets pressed by the last line in `viewDidLoad`, and the `buttonAction` function gets called.

Comment: This looks do-able although, as I'm new to iOS development, I don't think this is completely Swift code due to the last line in the first block of code. Sorry, but I forgot to mention that the button is essentially calling a `calculateResults()` function which is also contained in `refreshUI()`. So at first through the app load, `calculateResults()` is also called to calculate and render the UIViewCollection--not solely through the button-click.